# How to write Virtual Audio device Driver in various platforms?

Tags: linux, windows, driver, jack, a2dp

**Problem**

Hello, I am planning to develop a utility software that allows us to stream audio from multiple devices to a single device and microphone audio from the single audio to multiple devices. So how can I implement a Virtual device so that one endpoint can have a Virtual speaker so it can transfer audio to another device via the network and then play it at the same time it should also support a virtual microphone so it can receive microphone data from another device and feed the data to the system.

**Why**

I need to implement this software so If I have a single Bluetooth device and it is connected to a single device with this software it can receive audio from all devices and send microphone input to all devices.

**What I have tried already**

I have already looked at A2DP Protocol In windows but I don't know if it supports another laptop instead of mobile and I don't know if there is an [API like this in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76496966/how-to-initialize-linux-as-a2dp-sink-for-a-bluetooth-device), Also I have looked at [jack](https://jackaudio.org/) but don't know what this does exactly or if it well suited for my problem

**What I am Asking**

How to implement virtual audio device drivers in various platforms(Windows/Linux/Android/MAC) is there any high-level APIs for this task instead of writing our own driver from scratch using platform-specific APIs?

**Any Better Plans**

Are there any better plans than this without implementing a virtual device driver. Any suggestions are welcome Thanks.